# Why did the answer to my question disappear along with relevant comments?

Tags: support

Joey answered my question and there was some discussion of relevant comments that were extremely valuable.  Now, not only has the question been changed to protected but Joey's answer and the valuable comments are gone :(

What happened?

[Reactance / Inductance / Impedance of a 1:1 Transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70760/reactance-inductance-impedance-of-a-11-transformer)

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/many-new-user-accountsanswerssuspensions-and-protected-questions

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer I wrote in chat (slightly improved):

I didn't investigate, but what usually happens is this:

- a lot of bullshit answers are posted by a single user;
- along with an incidental / accidental reasonable one by that same user;
- the user is automatically removed by the sytem for all the poor answers being flagged by the users;
- with that the incidental reasonable answer disappears together with the poor answers.

Comment: But that's not what happened.  Joey was the only one who answered.  It was a reasonable answer and I went back and forth with some comments with him to get things completely cleared up.  No one else appeared to even be participating or commenting.  I don't see why anyone would have been flagging.

Comment: @Jim, it probably wasn't related to your question. Take a read of the link W5VO provided in a comment and have a look at my comments. Sometimes the same person provides reasonable answers to one question and then goes off and suggests abusive edits and total nonsense answers on other questions.